# wordpress conditional change login logout link

Tags: wordpress, authentication, hyperlink

I am making a site and the client needs a login link that turns into a logout link when a user is logged in.

To achieve this, I use this code in my header.php file:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<a href="'.wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ).'" title="Logout" class="hunderline">Logout</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="'.wp_login_url( get_permalink() ).'" title="Login" class="hunderline">Login</a>';
}
?>
```

How is that wrong?  It shows the 'login' link fine, and once you login, the link changes to a 'logout' link the way it is supposed to, but then the link stays a logout link, even if you use it to logout... help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional should look like this:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); ?>">Logout</a> <!-- This redirects the user to the current page after logout. -->
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); ?>">Login</a> <!-- This redirects the user to the current page after login. -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php and you will get a new menu item. When someone is logged out it shows the menu item Login. When someone is logged in it shows the menu item Logout.

```
function autov_add_loginout_navitem($items) {
$login_item = '<li class="login">'.wp_loginout($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], false).'';
$items .= $login_item;
return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'autov_add_loginout_navitem');
```